# wordpress paging bugs?

Tags: wordpress, paging

I am using wordpress latest version.

Currently my blog is set to custom permalink /index.php/%postname%/

`http://abc.com/blog/index.php` (working fine)

but when click on NEXT button to go to page 2, it fail.

It suppose to go to `http://abc.com/blog/index.php/page/2/`

But it go to `http://abc.com/blog/index.php/Index.php/page/2/`

(an extra /Index.php/ is being added....)

This happen only to page 2.
At page 2 go to page 3 onwards, the url is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to fix.

Just put a line at 
clean_url() function in wp-includes/formatting.php:

```
$url = str_replace('index.php/Index.php','index.php',$url);
```

just give this line at the beginning of the function before any "if Statements"

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to use index.php to see landing page.

```
http://abc.com/blog/
```

Above url enough to see landing page

```
http://abc.com/blog/index.php
```

While i am visiting above url.i just seen

```
sorry, we couldn't find that page

Please try using the search above or follow one of the links below.
```

So rewright rule  considered index.php as page.

Then i couldn't see any pagination in url landing page.

Thanks